# Grouping within a group in r

Tags: r

In mtcars `mtcars$group <- cut(mtcars$mpg,2, labels = c("small", "big"))` makes a new column with groups "small" and "big".

Is there any way to make groups, i.e. "small" and "big" by `mpg` but within a group of cars with 4, 6, 8 or any number of cylinders represented in dataframe?

SAS 9.1 makes it possible by proc rank function with arguments `by`, `groups` and `var`.

Comment: Not entirely sure what result you want, but does `mtcars$group <- c("small","big")[with(mtcars, ave(mpg, cyl, FUN=function(x) cut(x,2) ) )]` do it for you?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by group by operations.  With `data.table`, after grouping by one column say 'cyl', we `cut` the 'mpg' with `breaks` as 2, specify the `labels` and assign (`:=`) it to 'group'

```
library(data.table)
as.data.table(mtcars)[, group := cut(mpg, breaks = 2, labels = c("small", "big")), cyl][]
```